# Call a specific function which is defined in an Array of buttons from an HTML *ngFor statement

Tags: html, angular, typescript

So,
I defined an array of button properties:

```
locationButtons: IButton[] = [
    {
      label: 'Customer-Hierarchy.LocationActions.SiteVisitButton',
      disabled: true,
      code: ButtonCode.SiteVisit,
      redirectUrl: 'this.onSiteVisitClick()'
    },
    {
      label: 'Customer-Hierarchy.LocationActions.ServiceInstallationButton',
      disabled: true,
      code: ButtonCode.ServiceInstallation,
      redirectUrl: 'this.onServiceInstallClick()'
    }
];
```

I want to call a function defined inside a redirect Url prop when the user clicks a button.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of locationButtons">
    <button ngbDropdownItem [disabled]=item.disabled
        (click)=item.redirectUrl>
        {{item.label | translate}}
    </button>
</div>
```

I tried with:

```
redirectUrl: this.onSiteVisitClick
```

.HTML

```
<button [disabled]=item.disabled (click)=item.redirectUrl()>
</button>
```

But when I want to call the function inside of item.redirectUrl() function I get this error: *this.testFunction is not a function*.
Code example:

```
onSiteVisitClick() {
   this.testFunction();
}
testFunction() {
    alert('Test');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the `redirectUrl` properties to the appropriate method:

```
locationButtons: IButton[] = [
    {
      ...
      redirectUrl: this.onSiteVisitClick
    },
    {
      ...
      redirectUrl: this.onServiceInstallClick
    }
];
```

An then bind the `click` event to the method call.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of locationButtons">
    <button ngbDropdownItem [disabled]="item.disabled"
        (click)="item.redirectUrl()">
        {{item.label | translate}}
    </button>
</div>
```

cheers

Comment: Tnx man :) It works like a charm ;). I tried with redirectUrl: this.onServiceInstallClick(). This implementation resulted with the automatic triggering of the function onLoad...

Comment: @akotech what if `this` from the `redirectUrl` value is not of the same scope as the method it's calling? For example, if `locationButtons` come from api? Is it doable?

Comment: @akotech this does not work when I want to call function inside of item.redirectUrl() function... For example: onSiteVisitClick() {this.testFunction();} does not work. I updated the question :)

Comment: @DomagojHamzić in that case you have to either use `redirectUrl: this.onSiteVisitClick.bind(this)` or turn `onSiteVisitClick` into an arrow function `() => {}`

Comment: @akotech life saver, cheers!

Comment: @MishaMashina sorry I dont fully understand your question. Can you pls give an specific example. thx